# Tailwind - Border bottom color is inactive

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

Forgive me if this question already exist somewhere, please let me know.

Today is my first day with React JS. I am following the course on Youtube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b0_Y_eU_SXI).
Everything's fine until 1:40:00 of video, I cannot show the bottom color of the buttons on header.

[Here is my Header.jsx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zoJwg.png)

[And here is my browser inspect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvzGA.png)

The classes "text-black border-b-red-500" are overwrited by other classes.
Could someone please help me fix this?

I try to learn React JS, tailwind and firebase

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Thanks Frank. I didn't notice about this. I will avoid it in next post.

Answer (score 1):

I think it’s related with if statement. You can try to change like this `pathMathRoute(“/”) ? “text-black border-b-red-500” : “text-gray-400 border-b-transparent”`

Comment: Thanks Sergey, your solution works great. However, I wonder why the tutorial project also works fine?

Comment: You’re Welcome. Honestly, I don't know. Could be related to tailwind or browser versions, but could also be another reason)